# How to control main timeline from external swf

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a main.swf and inside it is just a plain container movieclip. Using the Loader function I load an external swf  called content.swf inside that container. Container.swf has a button inside it.
Now when external swf is loaded in container mc which is on the main.swf stage, I want to move to another frame by clicking the button of the loaded external swf.
If I try to control it from the main timeline I get error saying

```
cannot convert flash.display::Loader@117e7041 to flash.display.MovieClip.
```

If I try to control it from the external swf I can trace the click on the button but timeline doesn't move to the wanted frame.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it seems that you are trying to cast a loader into a movie clip. Use the `loader.content` property instead.

```
var mc:MovieClip = loader.content as MovieClip;
//do whatever you want with mc
```

Comment: But remember:
"SWF files written in ActionScript 1.0 or 2.0, which are loaded as AVM1Movie objects, cannot cross-script SWF files written in ActionScript 3.0, which are loaded as Sprite or MovieClip objects. You can use the LocalConnection class to have these files communicate with each other. "

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using event handlers as shown [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#includeExamplesSummary) because in your case loader.content has not loaded 'content.swf' yet when you try to add it to your container.

Also it is preferable to cast like this:

```
var mc:MovieClip = MovieClip(loader.content);
```

For the simple reason that 'as' won't throw you an error is the object you're trying to cast is null or can't be casted.